# conditional probability, Bayesian, discrete

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayesian

I'm trying to solve the following problem. A dataset is given.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Measurement Number & Time of the Day  &  Weather Description & Play  \\ \hline 
1 & morning & sunny & True \\ \hline
2 & morning & overcast & False \\ \hline
3 & afternoon & sunny & True \\ \hline
4 & morning & rainy & False \\ \hline
5 & evening & rainy & False \\ \hline
6 & afternoon & overcast & False \\ \hline
7 & morning & sunny & False \\ \hline
8 & evening & overcast & False \\ \hline
9 & afternoon & sunny & True \\ \hline
10 & evening & rainy & False \\ \hline
11 & evening & sunny & False \\ \hline
12 & morning & sunny & True \\ \hline
13 & morning & overcast & False \\ \hline
14 & afternoon & sunny & True \\ \hline
15 & morning & rainy & False \\ \hline
16 & afternoon & overcast & True \\ \hline
17 & afternoon & sunny & True \\ \hline
18 & afternoon & rainy & True \\ \hline
19 & afternoon & sunny & True \\ \hline
20 & evening & overcast & False \\ \hline
21 & afternoon & sunny & False \\ \hline
\end{array}

I'm trying to estimate using Naive Bayesian: $P(\textrm{True} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>)$. The Naive Bayesian approach relies on the assumption that the input variables (Time of the Day and Measurement Description) are independent.

What I did:
$P(\textrm{True} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>) = \frac{P(\textrm{True}) \cdot P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{True} ) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{True}) }{P(\textrm{afternoon}) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny})} = \\
\frac{9/21 \cdot 7/9 \cdot 7/9}{9/21 \cdot 10/21} \approx 1.27$

I think the correct answer should be 5/6.

Can someone help?

Comment: Your are right to think that $5/6$ is the correct answer. I have no idea how you came up with that calculation. You could just use the definition of conditional probability, $P (A | B) = P(A \cap B)/ P(B)$.

Comment: I got the calculation method from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier The idea is to illustrate how Naive Bayesian Classifiers work for Machine Learning.

Comment: Play is the class you want to estimate and Time of the Day and Weather Description are the input features. In the Naive Bayesian Approach, you assume independence of the input variables.

Comment: But $P(sunny, afternoon) = 6/21 \neq 9/21 \cdot 10/21 = P(afternoon) P(sunny)$, so you cannot just assume independence when it is clearly not given!

Comment: According to Wikipedia, in the Naive Bayesian Classifier you assume that the features are independent.

Comment: However, in your dataset the features are not independent. Thus, Naive Bayesian Classifier will not give you the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to estimate using Naive Bayesian: $P(\textrm{True} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>)$. The Naive Bayesian approach relies on the assumption that the input variables (Time of the Day and Measurement Description) are independent.

No, it operates by considering the input variables to be [**conditionally independent** given a category (in this case 'Play')](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Probabilistic_model).

> > Now the "naive" conditional independence assumptions come into play: assume that each feature ${\displaystyle F_{i}}$ is conditionally independent of every other feature ${\displaystyle F_{j}}$ for ${\displaystyle j\neq i}$, given the category ${\displaystyle C}$.

---

> What I did:
>   $P(\textrm{True} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>) = \frac{P(\textrm{True}) \cdot P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{True} ) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{True}) }{P(\textrm{afternoon}) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny})} = \\
> \frac{9/21 \cdot 7/9 \cdot 7/9}{9/21 \cdot 10/21} \approx 1.27$

The appropriate formula for the Naïve Baysian is $$\def\P{\mathsf P}\P(\textrm{True} \mid \langle \textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}\rangle) = \tfrac{\P(\textrm{True}) \cdotp \P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{True} ) \cdotp \P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{True}) }{\P(\textrm{True}) \cdotp \P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{True} ) \cdotp \P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{True})+\P(\textrm{False}) \cdotp \P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{False} ) \cdotp \P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{False})} $$

Though, given the table you can (and **should**) test the assumption of conditional independence before using it (heads up: it fails); or *avoid making it* and just directly use: $$\P(\textrm{True} \mid \langle \textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}\rangle) = \tfrac{\P(\textrm{True, afternoon, sunny}) }{\P(\textrm{True, afternoon, sunny})+\P(\textrm{False, afternoon, sunny})} = \tfrac {5/21}{(5+1)/21}$$

Comment: Ah, indeed I made a mistake. You only assume that the input variables are conditionally independent and not fully independent. However, I am still not fully satisfied. The denominator should only depend on the input features in the Naive Bayesian method. Should it be: $P(\textrm{True} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>) = \frac{P(\textrm{True}) \cdot P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{True} ) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{True}) }{P(\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}) } = \frac{9/21 \cdot 7/9 \cdot 7/9}{6/21}=49/54 $

Comment: $P(\textrm{False} \mid <\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}>) = \frac{P(\textrm{False}) \cdot P(\textrm{afternoon} \mid \textrm{False} ) \cdot P(\textrm{sunny} \mid \textrm{False}) }{P(\textrm{afternoon}, \textrm{sunny}) } = \frac{12/21 \cdot 2/12 \cdot 3/12}{6/21}=1/12 $

Comment: But: $49/54+1/12 \neq 1$. How can this be?

Comment: That is because the Naïve Baysian assumption is *not justifiable* by the table.  They are not conditionally independent.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks.